# Use an intent to send data to my activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-intent

I have a server running that notifies the user with a statusbar notification that opens my main activity, how can I pass data to my activity trough that intent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Intent.putExtra(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```
intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
```

This method is overloaded and takes various types as second argument: int, byte, String, various arrays..

To get the data out use appropriate getXYZExtra(). For String this is:

```
getStringExtra(String keyName)
```

Comment: but how do I get the data in my activity? what's the event that is called when and activity gets an intent?

Comment: `activity.getIntent()` or `this.getIntent()`

Comment: `getIntent()` is defined in Activity. You can call it anywhere inside activity, also inside `onCreate()`

Comment: ok I tought I was calling getExtras from the wrong place but my mistake was that I wasent doing 'this.getIntent()' thanks for your help

Answer (score 31):

MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra_text", string); 
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity

```
 String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_text");
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Short, and with the necessary.