# Intent.getExtras() always returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to run an activity through a notification and event `onCreate` I would like to "redirect". To this add a thought on information in the `Intent` class. An important feature is that the class that generates the notification is performed through a service. I retrieve the context from `getApplicationContext` method provided by the class `android.app.Application`. Whenever I call method `getExtras()` is returning `null`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class OXAppUpdateHandler {

    private void addNotification(Context context, int iconID,
           CharSequence tickerText, CharSequence title, CharSequence content) {

        CharSequence notificationTicket = tickerText;
        CharSequence notificationTitle = title;
        CharSequence notificationContent = content;

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity_.class);
        intent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(OPEN_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_KEY, 1);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = 
            new Notification(iconID, notificationTicket, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, 
                                        notificationContent, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    public static boolean isUpdateStart(Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        boolean result = bundle != null && 
                         bundle.containsKey(OPEN_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_KEY);
        if (result) {
            bundle.remove(OPEN_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_KEY);
        }
        return result;
        }
    }

    @EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (OXAppUpdateHandler.isUpdateStart(getIntent())) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, UpdateActivity_.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post code that puts extras in intent?

Comment: try to get Base Context i .e  getting in Notification broadcast or some where else .

Comment: @ChangdeoJadhav the method OXAppUpdateHandler. addNotification (...) through code intent.putExtra (OPEN_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_KEY, 1);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm going to lean out the window and guess that your problem is here:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

You are passing `intent` to `getActivity()` and expecting that you will get back a `PendingIntent` that matches your `Intent` and includes your extras. Unfortunately, if there is already a `PendingIntent` floating around in the system that matches your `Intent` (**without** taking into consideration your `Intent` extras) then `getActivity()` will return you that `PendingIntent` instead.

To see if this is the problem, try this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This says that if there is already a `PendingIntent` that matches your `Intent` somewhere in the system that it should replace the extras with the ones in your `intent` parameter.

Comment: This worked for me!
I also include the code below because the activity was not always recreated:

`@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends OXBaseActivity
{
 ...
 @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
 {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  
  if (OXAppUpdateHandler.isUpdateStart(intent))
  {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, UpdateActivity_.class));
  }
 }
}`

Comment: The activity isn't always recreated because you've set both `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. If you want the activity to always be recreated, remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` from the `Intent` you pass to `getActivity()`.

Comment: It worked. I was passing 0 instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. Many thanks.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time, @DavidWasser Thank you!

Comment: @David Wasser You save me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

(1) Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114443/android-use-an-intent-to-send-data-to-my-activity) to make sure you are using the put/get extras correctly as I don't see the code where you are adding data the intent.

(2) It looks like you are not calling get intent and get extra and, as a result, not actually getting anything from the bundle (assuming that information extists). If you are checking for a boolean value you should get the data you place in the bundle as follows:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if (bundle.getBooleanExtra("WHATEVER"){
   //whatever you want to do in here
}
```

Comment: I add the information in
`...
intent.putExtra (OPEN_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_KEY, 1);`

and then recover

`Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras ();

boolean result = bundle! = null && bundle.containsKey (OPEN_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_KEY);`

Comment: But you're not getting the extra correctly. . . did you try the way I suggested?

Comment: In my case when I call getIntent().GetExtras() is returning null