# Bundle loses values between activities

Tags: android, android-intent

In my first activity I want to pass two String array lists to another activity, but for some reason when I go to pull the values from the second activity, the bundle loses all the values. Here is the relevant code for sending:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("fName", friendNames);
b.putStringArrayList("fIds", friendIds);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Friendrequest.class);

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();

intent.putExtras(b);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// creates notification
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("You have a friend request!")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent).setAutoCancel(true).build();

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Here is the relevant code for receiving:

```
names = new ArrayList<String>();
ids = new ArrayList<String>();

Bundle b = new Bundle();

b = getIntent().getExtras();

names = b.getStringArrayList("fName");

ids = b.getStringArrayList("fIds");
```

Now, after I create my notification in the first snippet of code, I check to make sure that the "friendNames" array list does indeed contain the correct values and I make a call to `b.containsKey("fName")` and it returns true, but as soon as I check the "names" array list in the second snippet of code, none of the values are there and when I make a call to `b.containsKey("fName")` it returns false. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Refer to this link. 
[Intent.getExtras() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338579/intent-getextras-always-returns-null)

Try

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
```

instead of

```
intent.putExtras(b);
```

and try

```
b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
```

instead of

```
 b = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: Hmm, still no dice. I added `b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");  
  Log.d("HERE",b.containsKey("fName")+"");` and I get a null pointer exception on the "Log" line.

Comment: Try names = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("fName");

Comment: No dice. I tried your latest suggestion with my original code and with your first suggestion. Is there something that I'm missing because the intent is part of a pending intent?

Comment: Your latest edit of changing the pending intent worked perfectly. I stumbled on that right as I saw your edit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your former activity (the one which sends the value) `intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);`

and access them on the second activity by 
`intent.getExtra(b);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are exchanging custom class objects then the class must implement `Parcelable`. If you miss any member while doing `writeString` and `readString` etc. then the corresponding member will be lost.