# My notification is not retrieving the extras in pending intent

Tags: java, android

i have tried most solution but still i don't get the extras when notification is clicked
i tried
**1**[Why the PendingIntent doesn't send back my custom Extras setup for the Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127957/why-the-pendingintent-doesnt-send-back-my-custom-extras-setup-for-the-intent/3128271#3128271)
**2** [Intent.getExtras() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338579/intent-getextras-always-returns-null)

```
                String itemID = dataSnapshot.child("itemID").getValue(String.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserHomeActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", itemID);
                intent.setAction(itemID);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(UserHomeActivity.this, 0,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ){
                    CharSequence name ="001";
                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(Channel_ID, name,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH );
                    notificationChannel.setDescription("This is description");

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),Channel_ID);
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setContentTitle("New Price Added")
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
                    NotificationManagerCompat  notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
                    notificationManagerCompat.notify(001,builder.build());

                }else {
                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setContentTitle("New Price Added")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
                    NotificationManagerCompat  notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
                    notificationManagerCompat.notify(uniqueInt,builder.build());
```

*Here is my Code For retrieving the extras*

````
        if(extras != null){
                // extract the extra-data in the Notification
                String msg = extras.getString("id");
                String sss = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("id");
            Toast.makeText(this, sss+" ids  "+msg+ "     "+extras.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.call);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0818283848"));
                startActivity(phoneIntent);
            }
        });     ```
````

Comment: Please what am i doing wrong

Comment: you should use  getIntent().getStringExtra("id"); , getIntent().getExtras() is null

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging the extras? try putting break points and see what your are receiving in through the intent. Check if the extra is actually getting passed or not.

If you are not receiving the extra, then your intent is faulty.
If you are receiving the extra, then the logic of how you access extras is wrong.

Comment: Yeah all the Data are passed and I have tried all the possible ways I know to get extras and it's always return null

Comment: Did you trying running through a debugger and see what your pending Intent had? To fix the problem, you need to find which side the error lies. Before firing the intent or after receiving it.