# Not being able to access my custom view object from another class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-view, findviewbyid

I have been trying to find a solution for my problem for quite sometime now but to no avail. I have a `customView` class that I add statically into my `MainActivity`'s `layout` (I add it in the XML file). I have a second `Activity` that needs to have access to my `customView`'s methods as it will retrieve data from it and change some data. However, my second `activity` needs to only access that same object of the custom view that was already added to the `MainActivity`.

I want it to look something like this:

In my **`MainActivity.java`** I would do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent btnIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(btnIntent);
        }
    });


}
```

And in my **`SecondActivity`** it would be something like this:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


 CustomView viewer = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom); //I want to link to the view I added in the MainActivity

 viewer.getData(); // Example of what methods I want to use here
 viewer.setData(); // It should directly set/get the data from the object in the MainActivity
```

So far I have tried this:

```
public static CustomView viewer = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom);
```

In the `MainActivity` so that I can then use `viewer` in the `SecondActivity` but that didn't work because `findViewById` is non-static.

I have also tried adding this:

```
CustomView viewer = (CustomView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.custom);
```

In the `SecondActivity` but then I would get an error that I am invoking `findViewById` on a null reference.

I am not entirely sure what I can do, I have searched a lot online and in SO but I still can't fix the problem.

I am still a beginner in android so I would be grateful if someone manages to help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can send your extras to another activity from ClassA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ClassA.this, ClassB.class);
            intent.putExtra("A", "A");
            startActivity(intent);
```

And receive it at ClassB:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.containsKey("A")) {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method works but am having an issue passing a value of data type Paint.Cap . I am not being able to retrieve that data type in my other activity. Any idea?

Comment: Are you passing `Bitmap` to another activity?

Comment: No, I am passing Paint.Cap

Comment: Try something like this: `intent.putExtra("Cap.BUTT", "Cap.BUTT");`

Comment: I was able to pass it in the intent, but I am not being able to retrieve in the second activity.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `views` of `firstActivity` in `secondActivity`. The better way will be pass data to `secondActivity` using `intent.putExtra()` method. If you need result back to `firstActivity`, you can use `startActivityForResult()` method to get `result` back into `firstActivity`

Comment: @MostafaOsama see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114443/use-an-intent-to-send-data-to-my-activity for sending data
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android for receiving result

Answer (score 1):

**A bad approach - But your code works**

You tried using

```
 public static CustomView viewer = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom);
```

in the MainActivity. You can get it working by dividing above statement in two parts assuming that you start `SecondActivity` after `MainActivity`. First define the variable and initialize it in `onCreate` of MainActivity after calling `setContentView` like following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static CustomView viewer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewer = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent btnIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(btnIntent);
        }
    });


}
```

Now in `SecondActivity`

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



 MainActivity.viewer.getData(); // Example of what methods I want to use here
 MainActivity.viewer.setData(); // It should directly set/get the data from the object in the MainActivity
}
```

**Your code does not work because your `CustomView` of `MainActivity` layout is not available before `setContentView`.**

> **A good Approach**
>
> Views contain `Context` and [Context should not be put in static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709918/warning-do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory) as they invite memory leaks. As the other answers suggest you should get all the data from your `CustomView` in the `MainActivity` itself and then you should pass it to `SecondActivity` via `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a `view` across `activities`. You need to have your `customView` with id `R.id.custom` in both of your `R.layout.activity_second` and `R.layout.activity_main` layouts.

You can think of an `Activity` as a class that manager what is drawn on the screen.When you start `SecondActivity` it essentially redraws what your `MainActivity` created using `R.layout.activity_main`.

Also, if you do not want to go the `Intent` way as other answers suggest, one way of referencing the same Object across activities is to keep it in Application `Context`. So you can have something like:

1. Make a `CustomViewManager` singleton class
2. Instantiate an object of `CustomViewManager` to your application class.
3. In your `MainActivity`, before your `startActivity` method call: set the values from `customview` to `CustomViewManager` object.
4. In your `SecondActivity` refer `CustomViewManager` to get/set values of your `customview`.